# Unresolved url reference(python django)

Tags: python, django, url

I have a an unresolved URL request and Not quite sure what's causing the issue.

I am setting a homepage on my application for context

My view in views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "homepage template.html")
```

My URL in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'homepage.views.home'),
    enter code here
```

The error given in browser:

> ```
> No module named 'homepage'
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Django Version:   1.7.5
> Exception Type:   ImportError
> Exception Value:  
> No module named 'homepage'
> Exception Location:   C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module, line 109
> Python Executable:    C:\Python34\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.4.3
> Python Path:  
> ['C:\\Users\\jodie\\Desktop\\NtokloMH',
>  'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
>  'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
>  'C:\\Python34\\lib',
>  'C:\\Python34',
>  'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
> Server time:  Sat, 7 Mar 2015 19:10:33 +0000
> ```

I thought I defined the module through the views.py and urls.py code, but pycharm is telling me it cannot resolve the URL.

As requested:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'musicsearch',
)
```

Comment: Show your project directory structure and `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Hi @alecxe  I have added the installed apps, how shall I show my directory? Shall i include an image?

Comment: If you write `'homepage.views.home'` in your `urls.py`, `homepage` is expected to be an installed app... but it isn't in your list of `INSTALLED_APPS`. Where is the `views.py` you refer to?

Comment: Better provide it as a text with indents. Btw, you don't have `homepage` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: oh my, A MASSIVE oversight. I do apologise, I am trying to build a test app for a job interview and I am a junior with no other experience than self taught. thank you! may be worth noting the company suggested I do it with Python and Django with no prior ;) I am very much in the deep end :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `musicsearch` is your only installed application that you made yourself in django, and the views.py file is in that directory, then

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'homepage.views.home'),
    enter code here
```

should be

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'musicsearch.views.home'),
    enter code here
```

Otherwise, if `homepage` is an application that does exist, you need to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` as such:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'musicsearch',
    'homepage',
)
```